# How to stock multiple returns from a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I am working on generating all combinations from a code like ABCD for example, 24 combinations for this one 1 * 2 * 3 * 4.

I have this function:

```
static char     *combi_switch(char *code, int i)
{
    char        *combi;
    int         j;
    int         k;
    int         l;
    int         s;

    combi = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * ft_strlen(code) + 1);
    ft_strcpy(combi, code);
    k = i;
    l = i;
    j = ft_strlen(code) - 1;
    if (i == j)
    {
        printf("%s\n", combi);
        return (combi);
    }
    while (l <= j)
    {
        s = combi[i];
        combi_switch(map, combi, k + 1, stock);
        while (i < j)
        {
            combi[i] = combi[i + 1];
            i++;
        }
        i = k;
        combi[j] = s;
        l++;
    }
free(combi);
return (NULL);
}
```

ini called by this one:

```
char            *combi_mix(char *code)
{
    combi_switch(code, 0);  
    return (NULL);
}
```

ft_strlen && ft_strcpy are the same as the libc contains.

So with this functions if the code = "ABCD", `printf` illustrates the 24 combinations that are returned.
I went to stock all returns maybe in a char ** or a linked list.

- is there a way to stock all those combinations that I `printf`?
- is there a problem using "while" loops in recursive functions?

This is one of the last functions of my project so thank you so much if you can help me!

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. `sizeof(char)` is **defined** to yield `1`. There is no sense in using it. And `return` is a statement, not a f**u**nction. Do not parentitise the expression.

Comment: this is the output of printf:
ABCD
ABDC
ACDB
ACBD
ADBC
ADCB
BCDA
BCAD
BDAC
BDCA
BACD
BADC
CDAB
CDBA
CABD
CADB
CBDA
CBAD
DABC
DACB
DBCA
DBAC
DCAB
DCBA

Comment: Introduce a new variable into which you save the printf results, like a big array.

Comment: Your functions are meant to return a result, but you do not use it. So what would the result be good for? Also you loose memory. To sum it up: your code seems to have multiple issues. Please rethink the whole design, use a debugger and something like Valgrind to check for memory leaks.

Comment: thanks for your quick tips I apply that immediately and also try a sized array.

Comment: I also think about changing all the fonction, I would rather prefer an iterative way to gen all the combinaisons I'm a bit lost in this recursive..

Comment: [This answers the question](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/). For the record, these are called "permutations" so if you Google for permutation algorithms you'll find plenty of resources.

Comment: @jdavin: As you apparently missed my hint, I try the direct approach: It is "f**u**nction", not "f**o**nction". No offence!

Comment: haha thanks a lot Olaf I'm at the very beginning of my studies I know this is kind of noob questions.

Comment: http://valgrind.org man valgrind

Comment: regarding this line: `combi = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * ft_strlen(code) + 1)`   1)  always check (!= NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code making it much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain  3) the expression: `sizeof(char)`  is defined as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  the expression just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code, (that `return` statement needs indenting) 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a single blank line.  3)  please include key comments that indicate why things are being done (we can 'usually' read the code to see how things are being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no any special problem with any kind of control construct in any kind of function. Use `while` or whatever. Now once we've got it out of the system, let's concentrate on the important question. How to accumulate the results of your function instead of printing them? It doesn't matter what the function actually computes, it's only important that it's recursive and each invocation prints something. We want to collect instead of printing.

First, a function should return something. Your current function returns a `char*` but it is never used. Your new function should return a value you are after, that is, a *collection*.

```
typedef struct {
   /* whatever */
} string_collection;
```

We don't specify what sits inside of the collection. It might be a linked list, or a dynamic array together with its length, or whatever. You decide what kind of collection you want.

Now you need a couple of functions:

```
string_collection* create_empty_collection();
void add_element (string_collection* c, const char* s);
void move_elements (string_collection* c1, 
                    string_collection* c2); // moves all elements from c2 to c1, leaving c2 empty
void destroy_collection (string_collection* c);
```

These functions modify their arguments. These are only example signatures. You may go for fully immutable interface if you wish:

```
string_collection* add_element (const string_collection* c, const char* s); 
string_collection* concatenate (const string_collection* c1, 
                                const string_collection* c2); //etc
```

In this variant, you create a brand new collection without touching existing ones. Each style has its place; use whatever works for you.

Now it's simple to modify the function:

```
string_collection* your_function (whatever parameters) 
{
   // First, need a collection to return
   string_collection* coll = create_empty_collection();

   // whatever 
   // whatever

   // ATTN: old code was: printf ("%s", something), now do this:
   add_elememt (coll, something); 

   // whatever 
   // whatever

   // ATTN: old code was: your_function(whatever parameters), now do this:
   string_collection* new_coll = your_function(whatever parameters);
   move_elements (coll, new_coll);
   destroy_collection (new_coll);

   // whatever 
   // whatever

   // ATTN: old code was: return something, now do this:
   return coll;
}
```

When you call your function, you now do:

```
string_collection* coll = your_function (whatever parameters)'
// do something with the collection
destroy_collection (coll);
```

Here we have just learned to accumulate recursive function results. Awesome!

On a related note, your function `malloc`s a string each time it's called, but there's no `free` in sight. This is bad (a memory leak). Please add

```
free (combi);
```

where appropriate. In your case this means before any `return` statement. (It's a good practice to have a single `return` statement in the end of the function, instead of multiple statements scattered throughout the body; this is one reason for that).

Comment: so nice thank you, I used printf in order to see what I wanted to stock, of course I will free and everything when the algo will show some results.

Comment: I just need to generate all possible permutations of N elems starting like that: 12345 12354 12453 12435 12534 12543 13542 ... .

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify the program using below logic

```
char str[]="ABCD";
     int i,j,k,l,count=0;
     char temp;
      l=strlen(str);
      j=0;
      k=1;
      for(i=0;i<factorial(l);i++)
       {
        if(j==l)
         {
          j=0;
         }
        if(k==l)
         {
          k=0;
         }
        temp=str[j];
        str[j]=str[k];
        str[k]=temp;
        printf("%s\n",str);
        j++;
        k++;
       }
```

for more info you can [see here](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/2016/03/c-program-to-print-all-posstion.html)